# Selecting specific shapefiles using select layer by attribute

Tags: arcpy

I have a shapefile for counties containing many fields, among which `Pop_Descrp` is one of the field. I need to select the counties with `"Highly Increased"` attribute under the field and export it. I am not being able to make a correct expression for query.

Can anyone help me with this?

```py
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace=r"Z:\Ash Tree Project\Shapefiles_Arkansas"
env.OverwriteOutput=True

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("County_AR.shp","County_layer")

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("County_layer", "NEW_SELECTION", "[Pop_Descrp]='Highly Increased'" )

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("County_layer", "HighPopR_counties.shp")
```

Comment: I think this would be better researched/asked at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong field delimiters for your data type.  For shapefiles you need to use double-quote marks instead of square brackets:

```py
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("County_Layer", "NEW_SELECTION", """"Pop_Descrp" = 'Highly Increased'""")
```

Different spatial file types require different field delimiters.  Some have no delimiters `Pop_Descrp`, some require square brackets `[Pop_Descrp]`, and others (including shapefiles) require double-quotes `"Pop_Descrp"`

To save guess-work on which delimiters to use, the best way to handle these is to use the arcpy function [*Add Field Delimiters* `arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/addfielddelimiters.htm)

> The field delimiters used in an SQL expression differ depending on the
>   format of the queried data. For instance, file geodatabases and
>   shapefiles use double quotation marks (" "), personal geodatabases use
>   square brackets ([ ]), and enterprise geodatabases don't use field
>   delimiters. The function can take away the guess work in ensuring that
>   the field delimiters used with your SQL expression are the correct
>   ones.

```py
> # Shapefile:
> x = "{0} = 'Highly Increased'".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters("County_AR.shp", "Pop_Descrp"))
> print x
"Pop_Descrp" = 'Highly Increased'

> # Personal Geodatabase:
> y = "{0} = 'Highly Increased'".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(r"myPGDB.mdb\County_AR", "Pop_Descrp"))
> print y
[Pop_Descrp] = 'Highly Increased'

> # Enterprise (SDE) Geodatabase:
> z = "{0} = 'Highly Increased'".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(r"EntGdb.sde\geodatabase.dbo.County_AR", "Pop_Descrp"))
> print z
Pop_Descrp = 'Highly Increased'
```

So to make your select work, use the Add Field Delimiters function to insert the correct delimiters for your field.

```py
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"Z:\Ash Tree Project\Shapefiles_Arkansas"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("County_AR.shp", "County_layer")

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("County_layer", "NEW_SELECTION", "{0} = 'Highly Increased'".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters("County_layer", "Pop_Descrp")) )

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("County_layer", "HighPopR_counties.shp")
```